# Merge 2 integers into 1 byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit-shift, nibble

I have been working in this since yesterday and I can't seem to fully understand the bit shifting. What I'm trying to accomplish is that, I need to merge 2 numbers into 1 byte. The first number in the 1st four bits, and the second in the last four bits.

**0001** = 1

**0110** = 6

And then make them 1 byte from the binary "00010110".

After that, I also want to extract the 1 and the 6 separately. How do I do that?

All I can do is the extraction that I got from another question here:

```
int b = Convert.ToByte(value); 
byte[] b1 = new byte[2];
b1[0] = b >> 4;
b1[1] = b & 0x0F;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `value1` is `0001 = 1` and `value2` is `0110 = 6`, you can merge both values with an `OR` operation `|`.

```
byte result = 0;
try {
  byte b1 = Convert.ToByte(value1); 
  byte b2 = Convert.ToByte(value2); 
  result = (b1 << 4) | (b2 & 0x0F);
} catch (OverflowException) {
  ... // Handle 'Int too big' situation.
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. Your result consists of two bytes.

Comment: Yes, I plan on extracting them separately.

Comment: No, I'm not offended in any way. HAHAHA. I think you're overthinking man. Chill